# PHP remove double quotes from string except quotes after numbers

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove all double quotes from a string, EXCEPT when they are used for inches.

Expected results:

> this is "the first" line --> this is the first line

> "insert the 3.5" floppy drive" --> insert the 3.5" floppy drive

> I watched "the 100" and liked it --> I watched the 100 and liked it

> "bowie" mug --> bowie mug

I've tried this regex...

```
preg_replace('/"(\S*?)"/', '$1', $term);
```

...but it barely works. This is what happens:

> this is "the first" line --> this is "the first" line

> "insert the 3.5" floppy drive" --> "insert the 3.5" floppy drive"

> I watched "the 100" and liked it --> i watched "the 100" and liked it

> "bowie" mug --> bowie mug

Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: You can get quite close with https://regex101.com/r/02VEBf/1. Demo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1802453927e89f8f24939a53b1a9540da386bafa, but it has problems with `I watched "the 100" and liked it`

Comment: I don't think there is a 100% solution.   Consider the statements 1: Copy the movie "The 300" to the 3 1/2" floppy drive.  and 2: Did you read the article "Copying Files To 3.5" Floppy Drives"?  People are good at sorting that kind of context,  but forget writing a regex rule.

Comment: If you can ensure proper format, here's an attempt using recursive: https://regex101.com/r/02VEBf/7 - you would need to run replace multiple times though for nested cases

Comment: How do you know " is not used for inches here `I watched "the 100" and liked it` ?